# How to build graph with loop and return that graph in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I have a graph of type (int * int list) list. Currently is empty like this: `(5, []); (4, []); (3, []); (2, []); (1, [])]`

I want to read from a file and add edges to that graph. get_v1_v2 takes  bscanf and a graph and returns a graph with the new edge. It works as a single command in toplevel, however when i try to incorporate it into something like a loop i can never return the graph with all the edges, it always returns me the initial empty graph. I think the problem is that is does add an edge but then that value is gone. I can't think of a way to make it work. Maybe using references but there's probably a better way.

```
let file_name = open_in "a.txt" in 
let sb = Scanning.from_channel file_name in
try get_v1_v2 sb g; g;
with End_of_file -> g;
```

Comment: If you're calling `get_v1_v2` from within a loop, you're probably feeding it the empty graph every time. Data structures are typically not mutable in functional languages. Instead of looping, you should recurse (passing in the updated graph to each iteration.)

Comment: Yes after lot's of struggling i finally realized that was the way to go. Pattern matching + recursion. Base case i return empty graph then after the recursive call a variable stores the return and get_v1_v2 is called with that return value to add new edge and return once again another graph.

Answer (score 2):

If `get_v1_v2` returns the new graph, then you don't want to return `g`, which is the *old* graph.

So, you should have

```
try get_v1_v2 sb g
with End_of_file -> g
```

However, I don't see any definition of `g` in your code. It would be a lot better to give a full example for us to look at.

**Update**

Here is code that returns a list of integers read from a channel. This might be similar enough to your problem to be helpful.

```
let get_ints ch =
    let rec iget sofar =
        match
            try Some (Scanf.fscanf ch " %d" (fun x -> x))
            with End_of_file -> None
        with
        | None -> List.rev sofar
        | Some x -> iget (x :: sofar)
    in
    iget []
```

(It is tricky to handle the `End_of_file` exception.)

Comment: It's not working. The problem is that the try part doesnt work the new graphs. How can i make it always use the previous graph with the new edge connections? Something odd also is that my first edge is 1 -> 5 and that is the only one that appears added after reading the file i was  thinking it would be the last one the file.

Comment: Give a full example, it's too hard to guess what your code looks like.